# Messaging PlugIn (Carel Lotz) in Xamarin PCL?

Tags: c#, email, xamarin, plugins, uwp

So I have this button in my Portable Class Library that should directly attach an xml file I've created into a mail and send it using the Messaging PlugIn. The problem is that .WithAttachment() is not supported in PCL so I wanted to ask if I can get around this using DependencyService and if so, how?

Can I just return .WithAttachment() from the UWP class (as UWP is my target platform)? Wouldn't there be a conflict because I've read that the overload of .WithAttachment() in UWP is .WithAttachment(IStorageFile file).

```
private void Senden_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var emailMessenger = CrossMessaging.Current.EmailMessenger;
            if (emailMessenger.CanSendEmail)
            {
                var email = new EmailMessageBuilder()
                  .To("my.address@gmail.com")
                  .Subject("Test")
                  .Body("Hello there!")
                  //.WithAttachment(String FilePath, string ContentType) overload showing in PCL
                  //.WithAttachment(IStorageFile file) overload for the UWP according to the documentation
                  .Build();
                emailMessenger.SendEmail(email);
            }

        }
```

**EDIT:**

I've been able to modify Nick Zhou's answer a little bit to be able to send an email with attachment via button-click. I just changed this peace of code:

```
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker
    {
        ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.List,
        SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary
    };
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
```

to this:

```
StorageFolder sf = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            var file = await sf.GetFileAsync("daten.xml");
```

Of course you then need to create the file inside the app's local folder instead of the documents library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that .WithAttachment() is not supported in PCL so I wanted to ask if I can get around this using DependencyService and if so, how?

Of course you can use `DependencyService` to achieve sending email with attactment. But you could create two `interface` like code behind.

SendEmail Interface

```
 public interface IMessageEmail
    {
       void SendEmailMehod(string address, string subject, string body, StorageFile attactment = null);
    }
```

IMessageEmail implementation in UWP project.

```
public void SendEmailMehod(string address, string subject, string body, StorageFile attactment = null)
 {
     var emailMessenger = CrossMessaging.Current.EmailMessenger;
     if (emailMessenger.CanSendEmail)
     {
         if (attactment != null)
         {
             var email = new EmailMessageBuilder()
       .To(address)
       .Subject(subject)
       .Body(body)
       .WithAttachment(attactment)
       .Build();
             emailMessenger.SendEmail(email);
         }
         else
         {
             var email = new EmailMessageBuilder()
       .To(address)
       .Subject(subject)
       .Body(body)
       .Build();
             emailMessenger.SendEmail(email);
         }
     }
 }
```

As you can see the `.WithAttachment(attactment)` parameter is `IStorageFile`. So you need pass a file to the method. Hence you could create another `DependencyService`.

IFilePicker Interface

```
public interface IFilePicker
    {
        Task<StorageFile> getFileAsync();
    }
```

IMessageEmail implementation in UWP project.

```
public async Task<StorageFile> getFileAsync()
{
    var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker
    {
        ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.List,
        SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary
    };
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

    var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    if (file != null)
    {
        return file;
    }

    return null;
}
```

You can try the [project](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/MessagePlugTest.git) I have upload to github.

Comment: Thank you so much again, Sir! Do you know if there is a way to get the file to be picked automatically or set the default location to the DocumentsLibrary? Because `SuggestedStartLocation` doesn't set it to DocumentsLibrary (according to documentation it just remembers the last folder the user has picked or something like that).

Comment: @Nick Ok I got it now! And you Sir, you da real MVP! Thank you SO MUCH <3